# ID3 Algorithm in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a decision tree using ID3 in Python. I am really new to Python and couldn't understand the implementation of the following code. I need to know how I can apply this code to my data.

```
from math import log
import operator


def entropy(data):
    entries = len(data)
    labels = {}
    for feat in data:
        label = feat[-1]
        if label not in labels.keys():
            labels[label] = 0
            labels[label] += 1
            entropy = 0.0
    for key in labels:        
        probability = float(labels[key])/entries
        entropy -= probability * log(probability,2)
    return entropy

def split(data, axis, val):
    newData = []
    for feat in data:
        if feat[axis] == val:
            reducedFeat = feat[:axis]
            reducedFeat.extend(feat[axis+1:])
            newData.append(reducedFeat)
    return newData

def choose(data):
    features = len(data[0]) - 1
    baseEntropy = entropy(data)
    bestInfoGain = 0.0;
    bestFeat = -1
    for i in range(features):
        featList = [ex[i] for ex in data]
        uniqueVals = set(featList)
        newEntropy = 0.0
        for value in uniqueVals:
            newData = split(data, i, value)
            probability = len(newData)/float(len(data))
            newEntropy += probability * entropy(newData)
        infoGain = baseEntropy - newEntropy
        if (infoGain > bestInfoGain):
            bestInfoGain = infoGain
            bestFeat = i
    return bestFeat

def majority(classList):
    classCount={}
    for vote in classList:
        if vote not in classCount.keys(): classCount[vote] = 0
        classCount[vote] += 1
    sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.iteritems(),     key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedClassCount[0][0]


def tree(data,labels):
    classList = [ex[-1] for ex in data]
    if classList.count(classList[0]) == len(classList):
        return classList[0]
    if len(data[0]) == 1:
        return majority(classList)
    bestFeat = choose(data)
    bestFeatLabel = labels[bestFeat]
    theTree = {bestFeatLabel:{}}
    del(labels[bestFeat])
    featValues = [ex[bestFeat] for ex in data]
    uniqueVals = set(featValues)
    for value in uniqueVals:
        subLabels = labels[:]
        theTree[bestFeatLabel][value] = tree(split/(data, bestFeat, value),subLabels)
    return theTree
```

So what I did after this is the following:

```
infile=open("SData.csv","r")
data=infile.read()

tree(data)
```

The error which I got is "1 argument is missing" which is the label which I have to define and this is where I don't know what I have to put. I tried the variable for which I have to make the decision tree but it doesn't work:

```
tree(data,MinTemp)
```

Here I get an error "MinTemp is not defined".

Please help me out and let me know what I should do to have a look at the tree.

Following is the part of data and I want to generate a tree for `MinTemp`

```
MinTemp,Rainfall,Tempat9,RHat9,CAat9,WSat9
high,no,mild,normal,overcast,weak
high,no,mild,normal,cloudy,weak
high,no,mild,normal,cloudy,mild
high,yes,mild,high,cloudy,weak
high,yes,mild,high,cloudy,mild
medium,yes,mild,high,cloudy,mild
high,no,mild,high,overcast,weak
high,no,mild,normal,sunny,weak
high,no,hot,normal,sunny,weak
high,no,hot,normal,overcast,weak
```

Comment: Do you know who wrote the code? Maybe you could ask them how to use it.

Comment: I tried but he is not available and i am really out of time now. Thanks